# Sync a git repository with another private repository

Tags: git

I have a very big repo B, and I want to track it in repo A (which is in a private Network). Repo B cannot access repo A

I am automating this process so this what I have done so far:

1. I get a notification from repo B that a change has been made
2. I Mirror clone repo B on my Laptop that can access repo A
3. I add repo A as a remote
4. I Mirror Push All the refs to repo A
5. I delete repo B from the laptop (a must)

Now I have repo A exactly as repo B

My problem is that everytime I get a notification for a new commit or a change, I fully clone repo B on my laptop. Repo B is very large in size, Also we have to do this to work on multiple repos at the same time on the same machine. so we spent a-lot of time cloning and reserving a lot of disk space to only transfer one small change or something.

Is there any other way to achieve this without Cloning the full repo? And force pushing all the refs again?

Comment: Why is it a must to delete repo B? If you keep one clone of repo B, you could save a lot of time.

Comment: To save disk space, the script will track multiple repositories and each of them could reach 50GB in size or more

Comment: What are these multiple repositories? How many different repositories does B represent here? And how many does A represent?

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is quite odd but I'd do a [post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive) that send last changes to repo A.

Or a deployment script with Jenkins or Capistrano